# Does upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 damage my work?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, python-2.x, pycaffe

I'm currently working on Ubuntu Linux 14.04, and most of my work is about python development (deep learning using 'caffe').

Could upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 create incompatibilities with existing packages like 'caffe' or 'Anaconda' (for python 2)?

Comment: @idjaw its unclear from your link if python 2 is removed from desktop 16.04

Comment: I've ubuntu desktop 16.04 with python 2.7.12.

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading unused machine to ubuntu 16.04 (and if not possible, having VM of ubuntu 16.04) - check if everything works, and after that upgrade your main machine to 16.04

Comment: Good point @joelgoldstick . I've only been dealing with server. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.